# Javascript not loading option values properly in chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

I have a very simple script used to change drop-down list items based on the selection of a drop-down item from another menu. It works fine in Firefox and IE but it doesn't do anything in chrome and it's a concern. Chrome is indeed loading my javascript.js file but the functions are not being executed properly so it leads me to believe there is an error somewhere within the HTML that calls the functions.. Take a look!

Here are my javascript functions

```
function default_h1() {
    document.getElementById("showh1").innerHTML="<h1>Register to Play!</h1>";
}
function join_humans() {
    document.getElementById("showh1").innerHTML="<h1 id='bluefont'>Join the Humans!</h1>";
}
function join_orcs() {
    document.getElementById("showh1").innerHTML="<h1 id='redfont'>Join the Orcs!</h1>";
}
function human_factions() {
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML="<option value='Human Faction'>Human Faction</option>";
}
function orc_factions() {
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML="<option value='Orc Faction'>Orc Faction</option>";
}
function choose_faction() {
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML="<option value='empty_f'>*Choose</option>";
}
```

And here's the HTML that uses these functions.

```
<tr>
            <td><h5>Race:</h5></td>
            <td class="top" colspan="2"><select name="race">
                <option value="empty_r" onClick="choose_faction();default_h1();">*Choose</option>
                <option value="Humans" onClick="human_factions();join_humans();">Humans</option>
                <option value="Orcs" onClick="orc_factions();join_orcs();">Orcs</option>
            </select><?php if (!empty($errors[7])) echo "$errors[7]"; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h5>Faction:</h5></td>
            <td class="top" colspan="2"><select id="show" name="faction">
                    <option value="empty_f">*Choose</option>
                </select><?php if (!empty($errors[8])) echo "$errors[8]"; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Nevermind about what I just wrote about the error message loading the javascript file. I forgot I put the script search in my footer file last night to see if that would make it work, the path was incorrect for that search. The page still properly loads the `javascript.js` file from the header file.

Comment: Any messages in the console in Chrome?

Comment: Please show and hide instead of this horror and use onchange instead of onclick

Comment: What is the exact HTML that is being printed?

Comment: The way you've written this your second function call will overwrite what the first function call puts in place. choose_faction();default_h1();

Comment: Having two function calls makes no difference, i've taken it down to one function call for each one and it still doesn't work.. The html that is being printed is what is show in the actual javascript functions. The message i'm getting in the javascript console is: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: GET http://localhost/js_functions.js 404 (Not Found) - Note that i'm currently debugging on my localhost using chrome not online. Otherwise i'd have to keep loading updated files into the webserver

Comment: Which is it? *"Chrome is indeed loading my javascript.js file"* Or *"GET localhost/js_functions.js 404 (Not Found)"* Are these the same file?

Comment: I just re edited.. It Does load the file correctly.